# Search for a span inside a span in testcafe

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
<mat-option class="select-bank-option mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-selected mat-active" role="option" data-cy="selectDKCAD" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-261" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><!---->
   <span class="mat-option-text"><!----><img class="margin-right-10 ng-star-inserted" height="14px" src="/public/images/flags/dk.svg">
   <span>CAD - DnB - Bank DK CAD - 96321234567896</span><!----></span>
   <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
</mat-option>
```

I am trying to select the span depending on the name of it.

I am trying to click on a dropdown menu generated by angular, that has the text "CAD - DnB - Bank DK CAD - 96321234567896"

I have tried:

```
    .click(Selector('mat-option-text').with(bank))
```

and

```
.click(Selector('span').with(bank))
```

where 'bank' is the parameter of the method, and in both case, it can not find the option in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are trying to query based on `class="mat-option-text"` using [`Selector`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/) from `testcafe`.  I think you are missing a `.` in your `Selector`.

Try `Selector('.mat-option-text')`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you actually want to grab an element by **className**, not by name or tagName as you seemed to suggest. For that, this should work nicely.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-option-text');
```

This will return an HTMLCollection, you seem to only want the first (and only) result, so you would get the element like so.

```
var firstElement = elements[0]
```

If you want some more reading, this link should do you fine. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName